# How to cast a list

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class A and a class B, class B is inherit from class A.
Assume that I have:

```
A a1 = new B();
A a2 = new B();
List<A> LA = new List<A>{a1, a2};
```

Please help me how to convert List to List. I try to use `List<B> LB = (List<B>)LA` but get compiling error `"Can't convert List<A> to List<B>"`.

Please help me. Thanks.

Note: only .NET 2.0. Thanks.

Comment: I need a good solution with a big list. Thanks.

Comment: so? what's wrong with loop? ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to cast each item in the list, not the whole list.

```
List<A> listA = new List<A>();
List<B> listB = new List<B>();
for (int i = 0; i < listA.Count; i++)
{
    listB.Add((B)listA[i]);
}
```

Comment: But will very slow if LA is big list with a lot items. I want to know we have the best solutions?

Comment: @Lu Lu, yeah, if you upgrade your framework to 3.5, you can use the Linq `.Cast<T>()` method on the list to cast the whole list.  Unfortunately, with 2.0 this is the only way.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in .NET 2.0, then I beleive that you are stuck enumerating over the list and casting each element independently.  With .NET 3.5, you could use a "Select" extension method to cast them all with a single line of code.

Comment: With .net3.5 it is a `Cast<T>()` method to cast

Comment: Yah - I typically use a projection... list.Select(q => q as B);  Is that wrong?

Comment: `list.Cast<B>();` is shorter at least. Don't know other differences (but I bet there are) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
        List<A> la = new List<A>();
        List<B> lb = new List<B>();
        foreach( A a in la )
        {
            if (a is B)
                lb.Add((B)a);
            else
            {
                // ignore or throw an exeption
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something on these lines

```
LA.ForEach(delegate(A emp) { emp = (B)emp;  });
```